# How to see mangled name of C++ function in Mac Terminal

Tags: c++

I want to see the mangled name of this code. How should I do it.

I have tried this by compiling the code using G++ compiler and seeing output as ./a.out but nothing is printed. I have read about dumpbin.exe in windows but I do not have any idea about Mac.

nameMangling.cpp

```
// This demonstrate the nameMangling of function to make their signature.

int square(int x){
    return x*x;
}

double square(double y){
    return y*y;
}

void nothing1(int a, float b, char c, int &d){

}

void nothing2(char a, int b, float &c, double &d){

}

int main(){
    return 0; // Indicate successful termination
}
```

The expected result is
__Z6squarei
__Z6squared
__Z8nothing1ifcRi
__Z8nothing2ciRfRd
_main

Any light on my problem will be Appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Are you looking for something like `nm`? https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/nm.1.asp

Comment: See also `c++filt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `binutils` installed, install that package.
This is probably a good place to start: [Install binutils on Mac OSX](http://macappstore.org/binutils/)

Then `nm a.out` should show you the mangled names and `nm -C a.out` should show you the demangled names.